# which sql server edition is the best for saving data fast using entity framework code first?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm quite new to the DB subject, I hope my question is ok.

I want to build an application with a Database using entity framework code first.

Info about the DB I will have:

- Each day a new DB is created.
- A DB will contain approximately 9 tables, each of them has max 50 columns.
- The total DB file size should be about 2GB.
- The application will save data for 7 hours straight each day.

In the application will be 2 threads - one for creating the data and putting it in a buffer, and one for taking the data from the buffer and saving it in the Database.

My primary requirement is that the `SaveChanges()` function will finish as fast as possible since there is a lot of data that needed to be saved per day, and I'm afraid the "saving data" thread will not be as fast as the "creating data" thread and so the buffer will be overflowed.

which sql server edition should I use?

Comment: Any one - they really aren't differentiated much in terms of speed. The Express version is limited in database size, in memory it can use, and in number of processor (just 1) it can use - so if you have huge databases and very complex queries, the Express edition might suffer a bit.

Comment: This is too open-ended and can only be answered by yourself, by benchmarking various versions of SQL server on the hardware you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest one is going to be the most expensive one - i.e. the one that supports the most memory, most cores, most CPU's( assuming you give it all that hardware to use, otherwise it won't really matter). On the same piece of hardware, licensing aside, the various editions (except CE) should run at the same level of performance. The question really should be, which one is fast enough...and we don't have enough information to answer that. Otherwise you may be throwing a lot of money at a software license (and hardware) to get performance you may not need and/or that you could get by optimizing and/or changing some code.

Comment: thanks. why not to use the most expensive one always? is there are disadvantages to the most expensive? and why CE is different at the aspect of performance?

Comment: The only disadvantage is to the person paying for it....you can easily spend $15K just for a license on the enterprise edition. If money is no object, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use almost any version of SQL Server. Here is a comparison chart for the current versions on SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx
If you look there the express version only allows a 10GB limit on a database. So the express version seems good to start at, but if you get close to 10GB or want it a little faster look into the standard version.